# Loading system Library does not allow functions to be used when in a package

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, loadlibrary

I have a bit of an odd one.

Im trying to use a .dll library in my code and have a simple application which loads the library using

```
System.loadLibrary(libraryName);
```

When my .java file is in the default package, it runs perfectly with the .dll file in the project home folder. As soon as i try putting the file into a package, the code can find and load the library (it builds without giving an unsatisfied link error) but when you call a function from it, it then gives the  error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: main.MyClass.MyFunction(II)Z
```

which is defined in a class

```
public native boolean MyFunction(int A, int B);
```

I have tried moving the library to different folders and referencing accordingly and put it into the System32 folder but still no luck. It seems odd that it will work when it is in the default package but not in a named package.

I want to reference to it, hence the need to remove it from the default package. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a native method that you are writing the C code for? You need to run javah again if the package name is changed and rebuild the dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the package, you need to re-create the C headers for JNI by running javah again. When you do so, you will notice that the names of the C functions for JNI have changed - they now include the package names.

Basically, because C does not support Namespaces, in order to prevent name clashes, the package name becomes part of the symbol name of the C function as well.

If you change the package of the JNI method in Java, you'll need to rename the C functions and recompile the DLL.

Comment: Thanks for this! That sounds very logical, just need to spend some time getting that right!